# Google Adwords API TargettingIdeaService device type

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I have set up with Python a tool to retrieve Average Monthly Search volume of provided keywords (and generated ideas), however I cannot seem to find a way one could get these results by device type (desktop, mobile, tablet). The documentation is pretty confusing in this regard, one would think the `Platform` criterion could be used for the desired result (https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201802/TargetingIdeaService.Platform), but I have not found a way to send it and the only info I found on this was a Google dev saying it's not possible (but that was in 2017). Has anyone been able to successfully get Average Search Volume from the TargettingIdeaService by device type? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found a response from Google Adwords API team that at the time of July 4th, 2018 the API TargetingIdeaService did not support search volume segmentation by device type. It is unlikely to have changed since then (the documentation seems to point that way as well).

[Link to Google AdWords API Team response](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adwords-api/TargetingIdeaService%7Csort:date/adwords-api/sWglmo6gpqo/PcxYseKHAgAJ)